# python regex to construct a structured data structure

Tags: python, regex

I have some data which looks like:

```
key abc key
value 1
value 2
value 3
key bcd key
value 2
value 3
value 4
...
...
```

Based on it, what I want is to construct a data structure like:

```
{'abc':[1,2,3]}
{'bcd':[2,3,4]}
...
```

Is regular expression a good choice to do that? If so, how to write the regular expression so that the process behaves like a `for` loop (inside the loop, I can do some job to construct a data structure with the data I got) ?

Thanks.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen , let me add that info, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: To be honest, with what you have, i think a regex is overkill. `if "key" in string` and `if "value" in string` will work well enough

Comment: Souldn't the result be only one dict with serveral key instead of serval with one key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression can be more robost relative to using string slicing to identify values in text file. If you have confidence in the format of your data, using string slicing will be fine.

```
import re

keyPat = re.compile(r'key (\w+) key')
valuePat = re.compile(r'value (\d+)')

result = {}
for line in open('data.txt'):
    if keyPat.search(line):
        match = keyPat.search(line).group(1)
        tempL = []
        result[match] = tempL
    elif valuePat.search(line):
        match = valuePat.search(line).group(1)
        tempL.append(int(match))
    else:
        print('Did not match:', line)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work if the data is always in that format.

```
str=""
with open(FILENAME, "r") as f:
    str =f.read()
regex = r'key ([^\s]*) key\nvalue (\d)+\nvalue (\d)+\nvalue (\d+)'
matches=re.findall(regex, str)
dic={}
for match in matches:
    dic[match[0]] = map(int, match[1:])
print dic
```

EDIT: The other answer by meelo is more robust as it handles cases where values might be more or less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
x="""key abc key
value 1
value 2
value 3
key bcd key
value 2
value 3
value 4"""
j= re.findall(r"key (.*?) key\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\nkey|$)",x)
d={}
for i in j:
    k=map(int,re.findall(r"value (.*?)(?=\nvalue|$)",i[1]))
    d[i[0]]=k
print d
```